# Creating complete folder structure from Google Drive including paths

Tags: python, google-drive-api, directory-structure

**Aim:**

Identify which files are on my local HDD but not on Google Drive (online, non-synched), leveraging the same folder structure between the two solutions.

**Details:**

I use Google Drive as my hard drive backup and have uploaded >1TB of data by now. Once files are on the cloud I sometimes delete them on my HDD to free up space. The total volume of files on my Google Drive exceeds my hard drive space and I am consequently not synchronising my GDrive folder onto my HDD.

I recently realised that not all files on my HDD are also on Google Drive, so I wanted to add the missing files. Unfortunately I don't have an exhaustive list of files that are missing on the drive.

**Chosen approach:**

(Happy to consider any other approach if you think it is easier / quicker!)

Compare the individual folder contents on my GDrive and on my HDD using a Python script. Thankfully the folder structure is the same, i.e. on Google Drive I might have a folder Fotos/2019/January and the same structure on my HDD.

For the local copy I have not had any issues using the following code:

```
import os

hd_directories = []

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:'):
    for f in files:
        value = path+'\\'+f
        hd_directories.append(value)
```

This produces the following output:

```
D:\Fotos\2019\January\1.jpg
D:\Fotos\2019\January\2.jpg
D:\Fotos\2019\January\3.jpg
```

I have tried to get a similar output for Google Drive via their API but have failed miserably so far. The best I have got to is leveraging a slightly modified version of this script (https://github.com/beatleuk/gdfl) to get the folder structure as a nested HTML list, but then struggled to flatten this nested "ul-li" list into the right folder structure.

Edit: the example output I get from running this code is a html file with a structure that looks as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li> D
        <ul>
            <li> Fotos
                <ul>
                    <li> 2019
                        <ul>
                            <li> 1.jpg
                            <li> 2.jpg
                            <li> 3.jpg
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have spent almost a week trying to figure this one out but unsuccessfully so far... Does anybody have any idea how to best get a **complete list of all files on GDrive including their folder paths**?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: Sorry i am not a python dev so i could be wrong but i dont see any UL or LI in your code.   Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A fully reproducible example will be difficult given that a connection to google drive is required, but I hope that the example html output I posted is enough to convey my issue

Comment: I ran your [HTML here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_nested) it seams fine please describe the issue.

Comment: I am looking for the best way to extract the complete list of files in a Google Drive folder where each file is represented as its complete folder path. My approach so far has been to create a folder tree in HTML, however this doesn't allow me to easily compare the files as I might have multiple files called 1.jpg. So essentially I'd need to be able to "flatten" the above html nested list, so that the result looks like [D:\Fotos\2019\1.jpg, D:\Fotos\2019\2.jpg,...]

Comment: Google Drive doesn't actually use a file structure, folders are treated like files and all files have a unique `file ID`. Using the code link you provided from git I was able to make an HTML document with a list structure which emulates the idea of a file structure perfectly when viewed in a web browser as you can see here https://i.imgur.com/ciFOqs8.png which provides a friendly indent-interface for viewing which folders your files are in. Is this not suitable?

Comment: @Exclusive92 For example, is [this python library](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy) useful for your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Google drive doesnt have the ablity really to get the full path of a file when you do a file.list or a file.get.

The only way to find out a files full path is to start at the root directory and loop your way though all of the files getting all of the files in each directory in turn. This is a long process.  Normally I buffer these files and sort them out locally.

There really isnt a better way to do this. As you download each file your going to have to have built up what its directory structure was as you have looped though.

I have a sample of doing this but its in C# so probably wont help you much.